# Auto-update Property Graph (view or table) from original table

Tags: oracle, property-graph

In the property graph is it possible to refresh the created graph table or view it by PGQL automatically from a relational table or RDBMS when the original tables change? the original table which the graph was created from. When we add a new record in the original edge table, Changes in the property graph table may consist of vertices, if vertices are new or only add a new edge between two existing nodes along with properties.

I did my search in Oracle documents but my question still remains. I am expecting a solution on how to auto-refresh the graph table or view.

Answer (score 0):

You can run PGQL queries against the Oracle DB (2-tier architecture). This is the easiest way to ensure transactional consistency.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/23.4/spgdg/using-oracle-graph-autonomous-database.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/23.4/spgdg/pgql-property-graphs.html

In case you already use an Oracle DB 23c you also have the option to directly create, maintain, and query property graphs using SQL.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/23.4/spgdg/sql-property-graphs.html

Feel free to reach out to me for help.